# Users "crontab -e" save location

Tags: cron

I'm trying to add a new crontab entry for a user on my server by using a script. Unfortunately the user has no permission to write into the `etc/crontab` file, which is not too bad, because i can manually add the entry by using `crontab -e` - which works like a charm.

But as you may know, that's not a thing you can do in a script - if so, please let me know, because that's what i am trying to figure out right now!

Otherwise i'd be interested in where i can see those entries i made - without using `crontab -l`, because there has to be a file if i am not incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User crontabs are stored in `/var/spool/cron` and you can write to the user file as long as you format it correctly - `crontab` is really just a wrapper around a text editor to ensure that the file parses correctly and is in the right place.